# Pomegranate unresolved reference in Pycharm

Tags: reference, pycharm, pomegranate

I have installed a Package named Pomegranate on my project. I use Pycharm.
I then import at the beginning of my file with the command :

`import pomegranate, time, seaborn, numpy`

`from pomegranate import *`

`states = [MultivariateGaussianDistribution(means[i], numpy.eye(means.shape[1])) for i in range(transmat.shape[0])]`

`model = HiddenMarkovModel.from_matrix(transmat, states, start_probs, merge='None')`

Unfortunatly, Pycharm does not recognise the references MultivariateGaussianDistribution and HiddenMarkovModel. It states : Unresolved reference 'HiddenMarkovModel'. I have reinstalled the package many times but that doesn't change anything.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try hovering over the import statements. Pycharm should have an option stating "install package ___." If that doesn't work try looking into this website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html